# Comparison between Xiaomi RedMi 2 and Samsung Galaxy S4 I9500

Tags: smartphones, mobile-phone

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y, which is an older smartphone with Android 2,3 gingerbread. Due to some battery issues, I need to buy a new phone.

At this moment I have two options:

Buy a **NEW Xiami RedMi 2 Pro** phone which has a warranty and all other benefits (case, earphones, promotional price, property card). Price: 149 USD.

Buy a **USED Galaxy S4** which has a better price and better specs than the Xiaomi. Price: 115 USD.

Even though the specs on the S4 are better than Xiaomi, I still have some doubts. The S4 was released in 2013 and has been used since September 2015.

This question isn't intended to create a debate, is more to help me to make a decision. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion **Xiami RedMi 2 Pro** is much better choice than **SGS4**. Below I present pros for both phones:

**Xiami RedMi 2 Pro**

- it's new
- it has LTE
- it has DualSIM
- it uses MIUI OS which has regular updates

**SGS4**

- better screen (AMOLED 1920x1080)
- better camera
- it's cheaper

---

CPU and GPU are similar in this models maybe a little better in **SGS4**. The biggest advantage of Samsung phone is AMOLED Full HD screen but my choice would be **Xiami RedMi 2 Pro** because it has regularly updated OS (MIUI), LTE, DualSIM and it is **brand new phone**.

Comment: Being "new" to the market doesn't sound like objective judgement. Are both devices currently in the same performance class or how do both devices technically compare to each other? I agree that a newer midrange SoC may actually beat an older, susceptible to overheating, high end SoC. Regarding OS updates what does regularly updated mean in terms of MIUI? Is there any info about when Samsung stopped providing updates for SGS4 and which version of Android? With both being non-mainline versions of Android my guess is that both are not worth spending any money at all unless you have a preference.

Comment: Not "new" to the market but "not used". We are talking about "new" Xiaomi phone and "used" Samsung phone.

Comment: **Brand New Phone** Was the keywords, my girlfriend has the latest Sony on the market (because she can afford it), she's also an electronic engineer. So When I ask for her opinion, She agreed with You. Thanks for your feedback ivaan and @LiveWireBT .